# Time format in iPhone Photos.sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite, timestamp

I copied pictures from my iPod Touch into my Mac using iPhone Explorer, but in doing so their timestamps got modified. I am not an iOS programmer, but I managed to get to the data in `Photos.sqlite`

In `User/Media/PhotoData/Photos.sqlite` on my iPod Touch, I see the keys `captureTime` and `recordModDate`. The titles seem self explanatory. However, how do I translate their values into a human-readable format? e.g. `307867854.0` (captureTime) and `330936323.440785` (recordModDate). It doesn't seem to be in epoch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your times are the number of seconds since January 1, 2001.

The code to display the date would be something like:

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 330936323.440785];
NSLog( @"%@", date );
```

prints 2011-06-28 06:45:23 +0000

Comment: Thanks @Eric! I didn't know about NSDate and it's the info I needed to find an online [Cocoa NSDate Calculator and Converter](http://blog.paddlefish.net/?page_id=90)